# Do EntityObjects have a PropertyChanged event that allows me to access OldValue and NewValue?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework for my Model layer, and I'd like to hook up a `PropertyChanged` event that changes another property based on the OldValue and NewValue of the property. Is there a built-in method I could hook into for this?

The basic logic I want in my `PropertyChanged` event is

```
if (oldValue.DefaultPropertyA == this.PropertyA)
    this.PropertyA = newValue.DefaultPropertyA;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the OnPropertyChanging partial method. There you will have access to the newvalue.

The old value, is the value of the property on that moment, so you can access it just trough the regular property.

The structure in your code generated file is like this:

```
    public global::System.String Property
    {
        get
        {
            return _Property;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Property");
            _Property = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Property");
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private global::System.String _Property;
    partial void OnPropertyChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnPropertyChanged();
```

As you can see, you can use the OnPropertyChanging and OnPropertyChanged partial methods to be notified of property changes.

If you want to change the value of the property that's being set, you can't do this in a partial method. If you really want this you should change your T4 template to inject this code in your property or use Code First so you have direct access

Comment: Where do I find the NewValue in `OnPropertyChanging`? If I overwrite the method, I only have a string of the property name that is changing, and if I add an event handler I don't see the NewValue in the `PropertyChangingEventArgs`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm using whatever is default - no T4 template. I see how I missed this one before, I was looking through overridable methods, not partial ones. The only problem I am having with this is when the class is first created, its giving me an error `The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null`. I'm assuming it's because the property I'm trying to set is a Navigation property

Comment: Actually I got it working. I would only perform the update if the `oldValue` was not null, and made it a non-nullable value. Thank you.